# kendo ui treeview checkbox does not work with unordered list?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have my data already in a nested unordered list. I am trying to add checkboxes to each node. This does not seem to work. Here is a small fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/ge3Qg/

```
$("#treeview2").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: items,
    checkboxes: {
        checkChildren: true
    },
    dataTextField: ["CategoryName", "ProductName"]
});

$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    checkboxes: true

});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the `checkboxes` configuration option relies on client-side templates, which are not taken into account when the content has been rendered from the server. In more recent versions of Kendo (2012.Q3+), you can render the checkboxes in the list, and they will be aligned correctly. See [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ge3Qg/1/).